# How to add class to Wordpress's body element with time date condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm figuring out how to add class to wordpress body element with time date condition, there an example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {



function applyclass()
{
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();





if (n > 20 && n < 06)
jQuery('body').addClass('night');

else if (n > 16 && n < 19)
jQuery('body').addClass('sunset');

else
jQuery('body').addClass('day');
}
window.onload = applyclass;


});
```

I checked everything including folder locations and no console errors, but the problem is this script is not executing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're much better off adding a class to the body function with

`<body <?php body_class($class); ?>>`

than rewriting it with jQuery. See

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters

on how to hook into the body class in functions.php file of your theme.

Comment: Would you make an example rewriting it with jQuery? i'm not sure how it works with PHP

Answer (score 1):

Your if statements are testing the wrong conditions.

```
if (n > 20 && n < 06)
    jQuery('body').addClass('night');
```

`n` can't be greater than 20 AND less than 6. (You also don't need preceding zeros on numbers;  I don't think it's *wrong* but it's unnecessary)

You also don't need the `window.onload` part as the entire block of code will only execute after the document has loaded. Instead you can just call `applyclass()` in document.ready and move the function out of the block.

But apart from that, there's nothing wrong with the code, the logic is wrong. Figure out what you want it to do and change the conditions of the if statements and it should work.

Comment: I edited if (n = 21)
jQuery('body').addClass('night');   well it doesn't work

Comment: http://jsbin.com/econuh/1 - your code as it was in the original question works just fine. If it doesn't work in your implementation, something else is causing the issue and we'll need more info.

Comment: I think Wordpress is trolling me... i'm not sure how it works, you can try it with inspector www.powerupware.com  time.js and first lines of style.css

Comment: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ` might have something to do with it.

Comment: I removed logocycle.js which is caused this error but it wasn't important because it's working. Then shows no color animation on logo and it didn't work for time.js

Comment: I tried to add filter for body on functions.php from other answer, but it doesn't accept the time conditions, i restored the default now.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the window.onload statement.  it's redundant.  replace it with a call to your function:

```
applyclass();
```

the first line:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

already makes sure that this won't run until the DOM is loaded.

Comment: I removed window.onload and replaced with applyclass(); didn't happen :/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, i removed jQuery(document).ready(function () {} and some modified the statements, it works now. Here is my snippet which resolved my problem, feel free to optimize this snippet. Thanks for answering my question!

```
    function applyclass()
{
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();


if (n == 5)
jQuery('body').addClass('night');
if (n == 4)
jQuery('body').addClass('night');
if (n == 3)
jQuery('body').addClass('night');
if (n == 2)
jQuery('body').addClass('night');
if (n == 1)
jQuery('body').addClass('night');
if (n == 0)
jQuery('body').addClass('night');
if (n == 23)
jQuery('body').addClass('night');
if (n == 22)
jQuery('body').addClass('night');
if (n == 21)
jQuery('body').addClass('night');
if (n == 20)
jQuery('body').addClass('night');


else if (n == 6)
jQuery('body').addClass('sunset');
else if (n == 7)
jQuery('body').addClass('sunset');
else if (n == 8)
jQuery('body').addClass('sunset');
else if (n == 18)
jQuery('body').addClass('sunset');
else if (n == 19)
jQuery('body').addClass('sunset');

else if (n == 9)
jQuery('body').addClass('day');
else if (n == 10)
jQuery('body').addClass('day');
else if (n == 11)
jQuery('body').addClass('day');
else if (n == 12)
jQuery('body').addClass('day');
else if (n == 13)
jQuery('body').addClass('day');
else if (n == 14)
jQuery('body').addClass('day');
else if (n == 15)
jQuery('body').addClass('day');
else if (n == 16)
jQuery('body').addClass('day');
else if (n == 17)
jQuery('body').addClass('day');

}
window.onload = applyclass;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you're probably not looking for a PHP Function, but here is what I've done. This can be added to functions.php
https://gist.github.com/Garconis/11e7e4c316b4f5c4e5dfcbe7d916f5c3

```
<?php
// Add the times and days to the body classes
// e.g., date-day-wednesday date-ymd-20170614 date-month-june time-military-1317 time-pm time-early-afternoon
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_date_info_to_class_names' );
function add_date_info_to_class_names( $classes ) {
    // current day of week name
    $classes[] = 'date-day-' . strtolower(date_i18n('l'));
    // current full date YYYYMMDD
    $classes[] = 'date-ymd-' . strtolower(date_i18n('Ymd'));
    // current month name
    $classes[] = 'date-month-' . strtolower(date_i18n('F'));
    // current military time HHMM
    $classes[] = 'time-military-' . strtolower(date_i18n('Hi'));
    // check hour and add am or pm class
    if ( date_i18n('H') >= 12 ){
        $classes[] = 'time-pm';
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'time-am';
    }
    // check hour and add time of day descriptor
    if (preg_match("/(00|01|02)/i", date_i18n('H'))){
      $classes[] = 'time-early-night';
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/(03|04|05)/i", date_i18n('H'))){
      $classes[] = 'time-late-night';
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/(06|07|08)/i", date_i18n('H'))){
      $classes[] = 'time-early-morning';
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/(09|10|11)/i", date_i18n('H'))){
      $classes[] = 'time-late-morning';
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/(12|13|14)/i", date_i18n('H'))){
      $classes[] = 'time-early-afternoon';
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/(15|16|17)/i", date_i18n('H'))){
      $classes[] = 'time-late-afternoon';
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/(18|19|20)/i", date_i18n('H'))){
      $classes[] = 'time-early-evening';
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/(21|22|23)/i", date_i18n('H'))){
      $classes[] = 'time-late-evening';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```